# Is the string version of every model in Rails a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, model

In the Rails docs, [it says this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001596):

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
  # calls @workshop.to_s
  # => /workshops/5
```

Is this because the string version of every model in Rails corresponds to a URL for a particular instance of that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `to_s` method of `Object` prints out the class name. A Rails "model" is usually something that extends `ActiveRecord::Base`, and looking at the [source code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb) for that class shows it does not override `to_s`. My brain is too small to figure out what the [source code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb) for `url_for` is doing, but I suspect it is not just calling `to_s` on a model but rather doing more work to generate that URL. In Rails, URLs come from `config/routes.rb` so `url_for` must be using that in some way...